# Forms API custom element

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm currently converting some of our custom forms API elements into Drupal 8 equivalents, however I'm running into a couple of issues.

Firstly I don't seem to receive a 'triggering_element' back in my $form_state in the element process, it's there in the ajax callback - but not in the process, it was there in D7 and allowed me to implement different logic in the process function for different buttons / form controls being used. I'm not sure if there's a different way to grab it but $form_state->getTriggeringElement() returns null whilst in the element process, even if it's processing following an ajax event.

Secondly the $element['#id'] changes on each process now, as there could be multiple instances of this element within one parent form I was using the ID as a means of trying to ensure each ajax wrapper was unique. Now that the ID changes the ajax request works once, then never again (as the #id has changed, but the wrapper/container in the markups ID is the same). Is there a different way I should be targetting my wrappers in D8?

I've stripped down and included some of the code which will hopefully offer an insight into what I'm doing.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
class AddressSelector extends FormElement
{
  public function getInfo(){
    ...
  }

  static function test_module_address_selector_process($element, &$form_state, &$form)
  {
    $element['postcode'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Please enter your postcode and click find address'),
    );

    $element['lookup_btn'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Find address'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'Drupal\test_module\Element\AddressSelector::test_module_address_selector_lookup_cb',
        'wrapper' => $element['#id'] . '-lookup-wrapper', 
       ),
    );

    $element['wrapper'] = array(
      '#attributes' => array(
        '#id' => $element['#id'] . '-lookup-wrapper',
      );
    );   

    $entered_postcode = isset($element['#value']['postcode'])
            ? $element['#value']['postcode'] : FALSE;

    if($entered_postcode){
      $address_opts = test_module_lookup_postcode($entered_postcode);

      $element['wrapper']['select_address'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $address_opts,
        '#title' => t('Please select your address'),
      );
    }
  }

  static function test_module_address_selector_lookup_cb($form, &$form_state){
    $f = $form;
    $triggeringElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    // I'm unsure if there's a neat way to do this - I need to find this 'instance' of the element in the 
    // parent form so I'm able to return the correct chunk of form, in this case the wrapper.
    for($x = 0; $x < count($triggeringElement['#array_parents']); $x++){
      $f = $f[$triggeringElement['#array_parents'][$x]];
      if($f['#type'] == 'address_selector'){
        $ele = $f['wrapper'];
        return $ele;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The whole reason why Drupal needs to increment the IDs is to attach the latest Ajax settings to the element. This is done when processing the element, and as far as I know, the form builder methods do not have this information yet. 

My favorite workaround is to wrap the elements  want to replace with a `#prefix => <div id="my_div_id_that_do_not_change">` and a closing `div` for `#suffix`. When the Ajax callback returns the element, it always contains prefixes and suffixes as well, making it possible for the Ajax element to always run. Since it's hardcoded, Drupal doesn't increment its ID

Comment: @AyeshK Thanks very much for the response, I'm just struggling to understand in the instance I had more than one of these custom elements on the same form, would they work correctly if they all had the same ID? Or would I end up with all instances of the wrapper getting replaced? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry if you have more than one instance, you will need to either store a custom random key in form state and prefix with it, or, add some extra processing hooks to use the correct new ID once the Form API creates/increments it.